# Lines of code in your VB project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

What is the easiest/simplest way of finding out the number of lines in your VB project?

Answer (score 1):

- You might be interested to know how this can be a relevant metric: Wikipedia [SLOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code)
- On a linux/mac, to count lines in files matching a certain extension ('vbs'):

  find . -regex '.*.(vbs)' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
- Third party software, like [VB Pure Lines of Code](http://wareseeker.com/Software-Development/vb-6-pure-code-lines-calculator-1.00.zip/434307)

Answer (score 0):

if you're in Visual Studio, look at the line number on the left. If you want the total for all your pages, open them up, look at all your numbers, add them.

Answer (score 0):

There a ton of utilities out there that will count lines for you.  They typically count total lines, comment lines, white space lines, and code lines.  Just Google your particular language and you'll find plenty.

Answer (score 0):

What would you wanna see? Logical lines of code, or number of physical lines? Strictly, lines of code does not count empty lines, comments, and generated code lines. There is no easy way to find out lines of code in VB. Maybe you find something [here](http://www.locmetrics.com/alternatives.html).